# How do I draw a Venn diagram for A ∩ B = A ∩ C?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I draw a (clean) Venn diagram for the statement A ∩ B = A ∩ C?

[image]

This is the Venn diagram for sets A and B but how would I draw set C in this? Are Venn diagrams just not suitable for drawing these kind of equivalences?

Comment: In my mind, I am imagining 3 circles in space intersecting at the same line.. Although I do not know how correct this picture may be.

Comment: Take $\;C\;$ englobing $\;B\;$ (completely or partially) and intersecting $\;A\;$ at exactly the same semicircle as $\;B\;$

Comment: I know what needs to intersect what but how would I draw it without using 'ugly' shapes?

Comment: You can do it with rectangles.

Comment: Draw a stylized version of the upper body of someone. Let $A$ be her head and torso. Let $B$ be the torso plus left arm. Let $C$ be the torso plus right arm.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: In your picture, $(B \cap C) \backslash A$ is empty, which will not be true in general. She has to clasp her hands together too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way. The center is A ∩ B = A ∩ C = B ∩ C

[image: Venn Diagram]

Comment: In your diagram, $(B \cap C) \backslash A$ is empty, which will not be true in general.

Comment: True, you could rotate C a bit, that it overlaps additional with B but not A. It would still be valid for the original condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with:

[image]

I think this confirms your suspicion that Venn diagrams are just not suitable for drawing this kind of equivalence.

Answer (score -2):

Like this :)

The intersecting areas are all the same size, I think that's all that matters.

!(http://i740.photobucket.com/albums/xx42/saddamhansson/venndiagram.png)

Comment: I think you missed the point, Magnus.